# Is ORDER BY <column position> okay to use?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql

I was taught about the `ORDER BY` clause in SQL for sorting queries. I only learned about using the column name or expression, but after looking in the MariaDB `help` reference for `SELECT`, I see this:

```sql
MariaDB> HELP 'SELECT';

Name: 'SELECT'
Description:
Syntax:
SELECT
  …
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  …
```

So, I looked in their online documentation, and read about providing the integer position of a column to `ORDER BY`, instead of its name.

> You can also use a single integer as the ordering expression. If you use an integer n, the results will be ordered by the nth column in the select expression. [1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/order-by/)

Of course, it works great and I had no problem using it, and I shared it with my classmates. Later, when browsing the Oracle MySQL docs, I find that it is deprecated:

> Use of column positions is deprecated because the syntax has been removed from the SQL standard. [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#idm45780721005568)

Is this feature in danger of being removed from SQL entirely, and should I quit using it?

Comment: ORDER BY ordinal-position was actually ANSI/ISO SQL many years ago. (SQL-92 was the last revision with it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think positional arguments are supported by every database.  And even in databases that claim to deprecate them (such as Oracle and SQL Server), I doubt they will ever go away.  Apparently, they haven't been part of the standard since the 1992 version -- and were replaced by the use of column aliases (which is generally much more useful).

I always thought of the problem as the following not being the same:

```
order by 1 + 1
order by 2
order by coalesce(2, 1)
```

In the first and third, the `order by` is by a constant -- hence not ordering.  In fact, it becomes more confusing when you consider:

```
order by '1'
order by 1
order by '1' + 0
```

Once again, the first and third are doing no ordering, but the second does.

To further complicate matters, `order by 1` in a window frame would interpret the `1` as a constant.  This gets more confusing when you define the window frame in the `from` clause.

All this confusion is a good argument for why it never should have been introduced and why code should use column aliases.  That said, I freely admit that I often write code using positional numbers because they are very convenient.